Chrome Analytics Debugger Does not Work for GA4 hits?
I'm trying to use the Chrome Extension Analytics Debugger to check ga4 hits.
The Analytics Debugger is opened on my developper tab, but i have no hits for GA4, but an instance is found.
I'm seeing e-commerce GA4 events on the GTM/GTAG tab of the extension, but i need all
GA4 events, that should normally be displayed in GA4 tab.
Why is that?
Infos:

I'm using Chrome browser
Third-party cookies are enable

Screenshots:
image browser on selency.fr
image third-party cookies enable
Thank you for your help! 

The hits on your website are displayed, try to see if you have any chrome extensions that block tracking

open your network tab and check if you see the "collect" hits there

I found the answer thank you for your help guys! @MichelePisani
I had my VPN blocking the extension in my computer settings. Tricky to find it!
All good now
